# BING API Search Query

Tags: c#, web-scraping, bing, bing-api, bing-search

I'm trying to search the Bing API for a list words using the 'site' parameter to only get results from that site / domain.

I've tried to use the following as  a search query in bing

```
site:https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/ cake OR gateau OR victoria sponge
```

However this does not bring back appropriate results. I only want results from that site and I want to see if they contain any of those words.

Comment: You need a just read html content, and use HtmlAgilityPack to parse that html content to be able search.

Comment: I'm using the bing API which brings back a json response. I'm only really using the total_estimated_matches to see how many times a specific word or a synonym of that word is mentioned on the site

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be with "OR"ing of multiple queries. If you remove all the "OR"s from this query, it works. If you really need to "OR", you can make different queries with one phrase each time and site:.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is actually Bing Custom Search API. Use Bing Custom Search API, to scope your results from limited domains (in your case a single domain). It comes in two flavor:

1. Regular Rest API that returns JSON.
2. Prebuilt UX that you can embed in your code with single line of code.

Try it out here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/